# navigator.sendBeacon() sending Ping request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, navigator, beacon

I want to send a POST request to server with an object in request body.

```js
 let blob =  new Blob([JSON.stringify({
            id: _ID,
          }, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'});
      
navigator.sendBeacon(http://url.com/API,blob);
```

This is a pending call with request body not being shown.
[image: ping]

[image: body]

Is the approach right to send a POST call with request body with beacon?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever figure it out?